# Share a repository for multiple TFS projects

Tags: git, tfs

We are using Git for version control on a TFS server, and using TFS on-premises for planning and managing projects.

Our several projects are set as sub projects of the main one and it was setup using the SCRUM 2013 template. TFS has been upgraded to 2017 and we would like to change the projects to use the Agile 2017 templates.

It doesn't seem possible to change the template types, so we would be ok to have the old ones using the current Scrum 2013 template and the new ones using the Agile 2017 template. But both need to share the same repository, and that's where our problems really begin.

Is it possible to have 2 Main projects share the same Git repository?

Thanks

Comment: Your process template (Scrum vs Agile) has no bearing on Git repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many projects which deliver executables in a repository. All you have to be careful about is the build process. You might have to set up different build chains, possibly with a folder-path dependent trigger.

Git is just there to manage data. Anything else is you get out of *git* is just through how clever you were while using *it*.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are right, it's not able to change process templates. When you create your Team Project, the process template that you choose will be the one that you have to live with. If you want to change from the Scrum to Agile 2017 process template, you have to create a new Team Project.

And *Daniel/BikerDude* is right, the process template (Scrum vs Agile) will not effect your repo.

It's not possible to share repositories across team projects for now. And sharing code, may cause  quality loss. A better approach would be to **share the versioned binary output from your builds**. Such as through Nuget package management tool.

Another way is working on one large team project, **create multiple teams** under it. Each team would get their own workspace (sprints, etc) but all teams can share the repositories registered at the **project level**.